# Query to insert rows into a table based on another queries result

Tags: mysql

Its like this. I have a proyects table and I want to create an entry into a second (task_groups) table for each proyect that I have.

Like this:

```
SELECT name,keyid FROM proyects;
```

Now for each result in the above query I want to do something like this.

```
INSERT INTO task_groups (name,proyect,advance) VALUES ('Task for proyect proyect.name', 'proyect.keyid','0')
```

Where proyect.name and proyect.keyid are the values for each row resulting in the first query.

Is it possible to write a query to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `SELECT` query in place of the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO task_groups (name, proyect, advance)
SELECT CONCAT('Task for proyect ', name), keyid, '0'
FROM proyects
```